# Android - Change density border edittext

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I wonder if it is possible to create an editbox similar to the following image:

Image -> http://img600.imageshack.us/img600/5117/unledvxd.th.png

I can get in the green border, but I would like to increase its thickness as shown.
(This looks like a button in a editbox)

Any suggestions?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would make that image in to a 9 patch image, using the tool provided in the SDK, and just use that as the background of an EditText element.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a nine-patch drawable and set it as the background?

[nine-patch how to](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch)